# use HTML as a template for generating dynamic content

Tags: javascript, php, html-templates

I'm starting with an example because I do not know exactly how it is named.

Let's consider an HTML item code from a shop.

```
<div class="item">
     <div class="item-title">{$title}</div>
     <div class="item-price">{$price}</div>
     <div class="item-description">{$description}</div>
</div>
```

I'm using PHP, JavaScript, and HTML in  my projects, and now I'm generating the HTML template, adding PHP code in my file like below:

```
$MySQL //request;
$Array // data from database

while($rowArray  = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Array)){


    <div class="item">
         <div class="item-title"><?php echo $title ?></div>
         <div class="item-price"><?php echo $price ?></div>
         <div class="item-description"><?php echo $description ?></div>
    </div>

};
```

This is not the best solution because I have algorithms on each page, and are difficult to manage. There is an option to use the HTML as a template (not created in the javascript as a new element) and insert it in my main page using javascript and fielding also the terms with JavaScript?

I'm sorry if my request isn't clear, I'm learning on my own and I'm 100% sure there is on internet tons of information about this, but considering that I do not know how it is named, I could not find it.

Have a great day.

Comment: I am not sure if I entirely understand what you're asking for, but maybe this is something you're looking for? https://andrewberls.com/blog/post/formatting-dynamic-html-tags-in-php

Comment: @aghashamim thank you for your reply, but I'm looking for a different option. Let's consider that you have an external HTML file with the Item created and empty. Using JavaScript you will create an XMLHttpRequest, and then you receive data from the PHP file with your queries. After you receive the data, you will take the HTML file content, you will fill it with the data received, and then append it to your main page. With this information, I could be more specific? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Ahan, I think now I understand what you mean. What you're probably looking for is a templating engine. There are quite a few for PHP that you could look into. https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/847/top-7-best-open-source-php-template-engines

Comment: thank you @aghashamim for your reply. Seems to be what I'm looking for. Thank you!